# Not able to print python code in R shiny dashboard

Tags: python, r

i am not sure what is wrong with the below code. I am not able to run the below python code
ui.R file..........................................

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(reticulate)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
    dashboardBody(
        # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
        fluidRow(
            box(actionButton("upload","Upload",width = 150),
                actionButton("clear_upload","Clear",width = 150),
                verbatimTextOutput("code"))
        )
    )
)
```

server.R file

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    get_code <- eventReactive(input$upload,{
        py_run_string("def add(x, y):return x + (y+12)")
        py_run_string("print(add(5,1))")
    })

    observeEvent(input$upload, {
        output$code <- renderPrint(get_code())
        })

    observeEvent(input$clear_upload, {
        output$code <- renderPrint("")
        })
}
```

Comment: Hi all, Can anyone help me in this please

Comment: Hi. Could you elaborate what would be the wanted output? What should happen when you press the action buttons?

Comment: Actually, I need to print 18, since it is ````return x + (y+12)````